# How to listen to events fired by dispatcher

Tags: laravel

I’m using a package that fires an event using `Illuminate\Contracts\Events\Dispatcher`.

It fires an event like this:

```
public function __construct(Dispatcher $events)
{
  $this->events = $events;
}
```

And then

```
$this->events->fire('cart.added', $content);
```

My question is how I can listen to that event using a Listener or an event subscriber. I’m used to events being defined as `App\Events\ExampleEvent` and then using that to listen to them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `EventServiceProvider`, register a listener:

```php
protected $listen = [
    "cart.added" => [
        Your listener::class
    ]
];
```

The key in the listeners array is a string. Often this is the class names of an event, but it can also be a string like above, and it can hold wildcards.